# Why does this throw an OverflowException?

Tags: c#, unchecked-conversion

I have the following code in a method to convert any number in to a byte:

```
try {
    return (byte) Convert.ChangeType(operand.RealValue, TypeCode.Byte);
}
catch (OverflowException) {
    if (AllowArithmeticOverflow) {
        unchecked {
            decimal d = Convert.ToDecimal(operand.RealValue);
            return (byte) d;
        }
    }

    throw;
}
```

In this code, `operand.RealValue` is expected to be any number. For the example I'm testing with, it's an `sbyte` with the value *-13* (verified with the debugger). I can step through in the debugger and get to the line `return (byte) d;` ... At which point an *OverflowException* is thrown, despite it being in the `unchecked` block.

So... What gives?

Also, if you're looking at my implementation and wondering what the hell I'm doing - it's the result of all the gymnastics I've tried so far to not get this exception. Must succinct answer wins :)

Note: The exception message is as follows:

> System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for
>   an unsigned byte. ---> System.OverflowException: Value was either too
>   large or too small for a UInt32.

Comment: -13 is too small for an unsigned byte

Comment: Yeah obviously - but I want to allow that anyway, basically just reinterpret_cast it...

Comment: @SwDevMan81 Wins! Cant get more succinct than that.

Comment: So what byte value should -13 correspond to?  242?  115?  0?

Comment: But the reason is because [unchecked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a569z7k8.aspx) is for **arithmetic** operations and conversions: `The unchecked keyword is used to suppress overflow-checking for integral-type arithmetic operations and conversions.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously there is no way to interpret `-13` as a byte. At least not unless you specify some extra context. Perhaps you mean to treat `-13` as an unsigned char (value between -128 and 127) and then reinterpret the bits as a signed char (byte).

If that's what you are trying to do then you could use the [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.BitConverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is caused by using `Convert.ChangeType`.. which is why the `unchecked` block may not be working in various circumstances (and why you're no doubt posting this question).

`Convert.ChangeType` ends up calling `IConvertible.To<TypeHere>`. The `ToByte` method on `System.SByte` is like this:

```
public static byte ToByte(sbyte value) {
    if (value < 0) {
        throw new OverflowException(Environment.GetResourceString("Overflow_Byte"));
    }

    return (byte)value;
}
```

It's explicitly throwing the exception.. hence why `unchecked` is useless.

Comment: He said that the break point on the return statement hits. He is obviously getting past the conversion

Answer (score 0):

From your comment:

> basically just reinterpret_cast it...

I gather that you want to convert a `sbyte` with a value `-13` and interpret that as a `byte`.

So simply cast it:

```
sbyte s = -13;
byte u = (byte)s; // u = 243
```

Comment: You could do the same thing by just casting to `sbyte` and then to `byte`.  It would be clearer code.

Comment: For some reason I was thinking that would mess up the sign... would it not end up being `+13`?

Comment: Try it out and see for yourself.  The result is the same.